Eigenvalues of a 8x8 Matrix
This is the 6th problem of the TACA in August, 2023. One have 2 hours to solve 15 problems.
I am wondering how to calculate the eigenvalues of the following 8 by 8 matrix by hand.
Note that this is NOT a circulant matrix.
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
10  &-9  &  &  &  &  &  &-9 \\
-9  &10  &-9  &  &  &  &  & \\
  &9  &10  &9  &  &  &  & \\
  &  &9  &10  &9  &  &  & \\
  &  &  &9  &10  &9  &  & \\
  &  &  &  &-9  &10  &-9  & \\
  &  &  &  &  &-9  &10  &-9 \\
-9  &  &  &  &  &  &-9  &10
\end{pmatrix}$
(Required in the contest: Let $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_8$ be the eigenvalues of A, find the value of $\lambda_6$.I have no idea if this makes it simpler.)
Calculated with computers,$\lambda_1=\lambda_2=10-9\sqrt{2},\lambda_3=\lambda_4=\lambda_5=\lambda_6=10,\lambda_7=\lambda_8=10+9\sqrt{2}$
I have no idea how to solve $|\lambda I-A|=O$ in a normal way. Maybe I need new methods?
When I participated, I mistook A for the following circulant matrix B.
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
10  &-9  &  &  &  &  &  &-9 \\
-9  &10  &-9  &  &  &  &  & \\
  &-9  &10  &-9  &  &  &  & \\
  &  &-9  &10  &-9  &  &  & \\
  &  &  &-9  &10  &-9  &  & \\
  &  &  &  &-9  &10  &-9  & \\
  &  &  &  &  &-9  &10  &-9 \\
-9  &  &  &  &  &  &-9  &10
\end{pmatrix}$
I took the 8th unit roots to $-9x^7-9x+10$ and got $\lambda_1=10-18,\lambda_2=\lambda_3=10-9\sqrt{2},\lambda_4=\lambda_5=10,\lambda_6=\lambda_7=10+9\sqrt{2},\lambda_8=10+18$.
I don't know if this helps with the original problem either.

It's notable that $A$ can be written in the form $A = 10I + 9M$, where $M$ is a relatively nice matrix. Finding the eigenvalues of $A$ is equivalent to finding the eigenvalues of $M$. In order to find the eigenvalues of $M$, it is helpful to note that $M^3$ is a rank-4 matrix.

Granted, all of that makes for a relatively painless computation if you know what to look for in advance, but I have no idea how you would think to do this given the time constraint. Perhaps the constant diagonal serves as a hint that subtracting $10I$ is a good idea.

Writing $A=10I+9M$ and looking for the eigenvalues of $M$ is a very natural reaction, but this alone doesn't help much indeed.

An interesting observation: take
$$
P = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right],\dots
$$

...and
$$
M_1 =
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1\
\hline
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\
-1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right].
$$
Then $M_1 = PMP^T$.
